# Is a neural network's hidden layer the same thing as the hidden state?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology

I am doing a terminology report on ANNs, and I am trying to understand whether the 
'hidden layer' means the same thing as the 'hidden state' of a network. I have only found the second term when discussing RNNs or LSTMs, so is it only relevant to those?
I apologise if this is a silly question. This is all very fascinating but also very new to me, so I have lots of them.

Comment: Deterministic forgetting versus stochastic forgetting is how I draw the distinction: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/585696/8336

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hidden layer and hidden state are entirely different:

- **hidden layer**: this term is mostly used in feedforward networks to designate any layer located between the input layer and the output layer:

[image]

(each unit in a hidden layer is called a **hidden unit**, or **hidden neuron**)

- **hidden state**: this term is mostly used in the context of a recurrent layer, which contain one variable that is passed around during the recurrence, e.g $h_1,h_2,h_3$ in the figure below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The hidden layer is a set of operations (like ODE-Solver operations in Neural ODE models), and the state layer is a set of results (set of numbers) from these operations. In other words, the hidden state (hs(1)) is the result of the hidden layer (h(0)), and it performs as an input for the hidden layer (h(1)).

Answer (score 0):

Hidden layers: are, as explained, layers that are hidden from view on the path from input to output.

Hidden states are technically speaking inputs to whatever we do at a given step, and they can only be computed by looking at data at previous time steps.

Source: https://d2l.ai/chapter_recurrent-neural-networks/rnn.html